# PHP Uploaded Filename not printing

Tags: php, printing, upload, filenames

This is simple and should work but doesn't, so I'm obviously derping pretty hard somewhere. The uploaded file name should print after form submission.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file1']['name'];
        print($name_of_uploaded_file);
    }
?>

<form id="contactform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Attach Logo:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" id="uploaded_file1" name="uploaded_file1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the content encoding type set on your form open tag.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
```